# Choosing a service to associate a timer job with

Tags: c#, sharepoint, timer

I'm writing a custom timer job in C# and need to pick a service to associate my timer job with.

I've tried the local timer service:

```
: base(String.Format(JOB_NAME, Guid.NewGuid()), SPFarm.Local.TimerService, server, SPJobLockType.None)
```

This has been pretty spotty, we've had issues getting this job to run reliably enough on all servers in a farm to be satisfied with.

We think this is due to the timer service not updating with the new job sometimes.

Clearing the SharePoint config cache and forcing the timer service to update has "fixed" the issue, but we obviously can't use that as a final solution to the issue.

What other services could I possibly associate this job with? I don't want to associate with a web app instead.